# Typescript convert string to object error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a basic problem when i convert the response json from the websocket server to a ts object, but i cannot find where is the error...
Can you help to fix it, please?

Here is the websocket server:

```
const wsServer: Server = new Server({port: WEBSOCKET_PORT});

console.log('WebSocket server is listening on port 8085');
export class PushData {
  constructor(public push: string,
              public workflowId: number) {
  }
}

wsServer.on('connection', (websocket, req) => {
  websocket.send('This message was pushed by WebSocket server');
  websocket.send('Data pushed by server: ');
  websocket.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('Server received : %s', message);
    const todaysDate = new Date();
    // websocket.send('Data pushed by server: ' + todaysDate.toString());
    const request1 = new PushData('data', 30);
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(request1));
   }
}
```

Here is the client 
Class service:

```
private faceSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
createObservableSocket(url: string): Observable<string> {
  this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
  return new Observable(
    observer => {
      this.ws.onmessage = (event) => observer.next(event.data);
      this.ws.onerror = (event) => observer.error(event);
      this.ws.onclose = (event) => observer.complete();
    }
  );
}
```

And here is client component where i want to do the convert:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.drawOverlayPicture();

  // subscribe to the subject
  this.subscription = this.wsService.getFaceSubject()
    .subscribe((data: PushData) => {
        if (data !== null) {
          console.log('received data from server', data);
          console.log('received data from server push=', data.push);
          // var ob = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
          // console.log('received data from server, workflowId=', (<PushData> ob).push);
          console.log(this.i++);
}
```

and

```
export class PushData {
  constructor(public push: string, public workflowId: number) {}
}
```

Here i got always te data.push = undefined.
Can you tell me how to convert the websocket response to object, please?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. What is `console.log('received data from server', data)`?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :**
The server will only push a PushData object when he receives a message from client, but he will send two string to the client on connection. This is why you get data.push is undefined, because data is only strings.

```
websocket.send('This message was pushed by WebSocket server');  
websocket.send('Data pushed by server: ');
```

You need to emit a message from the client in order to receive the pushData object !

Comment: Ok thank you, I updated my answer, I thought that this was a special dependency injection syntax. I learned a new thing thank you so much !

Comment: Can you tell me in this case, how to convert the string to object, please? i have tried to use <PushData> data to cast, but it doesn't work.

Comment: For this case, i use:   private faceSubject = new BehaviorSubject<PushData>(null); but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried also to use JSON.parse(data) to create an object, but i got the error: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0.

Comment: Read my answer again, you are sending raw strings not PushData object on websocket connection. You need to send an event from the client in order to receive a PushData object, so try in the createObservableSocket sending a message: after the websocket initialization: `this.ws.send('Give me a PushData Object plz');`

Comment: You server is waiting for a message to answer back a PushData object, this is what this line mean: `websocket.on('message', (message) => {`

Comment: Thank you, so you mean that i should call: websocket.send(new PushData('data, 30))  to send the object from the server?

Comment: But i think, with websocket, we exchange always ths string. That's why call stringfy to get the json string and push the string to client

Comment: Sorry, i understand waht you mean, but from the client, i get data which is a json string {...}, but it's always undefned for data.push.